# Hide minimize and maximize buttons on form without hide title

Tags: c#, winforms, formborderstyle

How can I hide minimize and maximize (but not the close) buttons on form without hide the form's title and icon too? I want to a `MessageBox` like style.

I've tried and failed with:

`FormBorderStyle` set as `FixedToolWindow` does the job let only the close button but does hide the form's `Text` and `Icon`.

`ControlBox` -> Hide not only minimize and maximize but close and title too.

Comment: set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` to false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties to false.

Comment: It doesn't hide them just turn unclickable

Comment: Yes it does.  Set your `FormBorderStyle` to `Sizeable` or `FixedDialog`.

Comment: my sorry, it really does with both set to false at sametime. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `toolwindow`